# Ordenar lineas tras un readfile?

Tags: python

Tengo un fichero con varias lineas tal que:

```
"PseudorangeRateUncertaintyMetersPerSecond",4.2033262571598,"DriftUncertaintyNanosPerSecond","","AccumulatedDeltaRangeState",4,"ReceivedSvTimeNanos",491720918491560.0,"TimeUncertaintyNanos","","SnrInDb","","FullBiasNanos",-1.2125108815424e+18,"State",47,"MultipathIndicator","0","AgcDb","","PseudorangeRateMetersPerSecond",-4.0109888367723,"TimeNanos",39458000000,"Svid",7,"AccumulatedDeltaRangeUncertaintyMeters",3.4028234663853e+38,"AccumulatedDeltaRangeMeters",-136.14045066658,"BiasUncertaintyNanos",5.4542302099749,"BiasNanos",0,"CarrierPhaseUncertainty","","CarrierFrequencyHz2","TimeOffsetNanos",0,"DriftNanosPerSecond","","CarrierFrequencyHz","","ConstellationType","1","CarrierCycles","","ReceivedSvTimeUncertaintyNanos",89,"CarrierPhase","","LeapSecond","","HardwareClockDiscontinuityCount",0,"ElapsedRealtimeMillis",14067926,"Id","Raw","Cn0DbHz",17.306573867798
```

He creado un programa que lee cada linea y la separa por comas.
Necesito ordenar las lineas del archivo según el último valor de cada linea.

```
lectura=[]
while True:
linea=f.readline()
if not linea:break

lect_linea=linea.split(',')
lectura.append(lect_linea)
```

El problema que me encuentro es que en vez de cada lect_linea guardarse como un objeto y tener tantos como lineas haya me aparece un unico valor en la lista con todos los lect_linea juntos.

He preguntado un par de veces y no he obtenido nada que funcione, ayuda porfavor

Comment: Pues lo probé igual y me funcionó correctamente. ¿Lo que quieres es que el resultado sea una lista con tantas listas como lineas del archivo haya no?

Comment: En python la identación es primordial. Procura que tu código esté correctamente identado.

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes en la variable `lectura` una *"lista de listas"*. Lo que quieres ahora es ordenar por el último elemento de cada una de esas líneas. Para ello se usa `sorted()` pasándole una función para acceso al último elemento:

```
lectura_ordenada = sorted(lectura, key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

No sé cuál será el propósito de esta ordenación, si quieres luego volver a guardarlo en un fichero o si quieres crear *"objetos"* de algún tipo.

Supongamos que queremos leer las líneas de un fichero, ordenarlas por el último valor, y volverlas a guardar en otro fichero. Se puede hacer de una forma directa así:

```
def ultimo(linea):
    return linea.split(",")[-1]

with open("entrada.txt") as f_in, open("salida.txt","w") as f_out:
    f_out.writelines(sorted(f_in.readlines(), key=ultimo))
```